# How to resolve 'System.MissingMethodException' in dotnet core

Tags: f#, .net-core, system.drawing, accord.net

To reproduce follow steps:

In terminal/cli:

```
dotnet new console --language F# --name "sample"
cd sample
dotnet add package Accord.Imaging
dotnet add package CoreCompat.System.Drawing --version 1.0.0-beta006
```

Download following [image](http://accord-framework.net/docs/images/imaging/sample8.jpg) and put in the project folder.

Change `Program.fs` to contain the following code:

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org

open System
open System.Drawing
open Accord.Imaging.Filters

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let bitmap = new Bitmap("sample8.jpg")
    let filter = new Grayscale( 0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721 );
    let sourceImage = filter.Apply(bitmap)
    printfn "Hello World from F#!"
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

How do I resolve the following error that I get?

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Drawing.Color[] System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette.get_Entries()'.
   at Accord.Imaging.Image.SetGrayscalePalette(Bitmap image)
   at Accord.Imaging.Image.CreateGrayscaleImage(Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at Accord.Imaging.Filters.BaseFilter.Apply(BitmapData imageData)
   at Accord.Imaging.Filters.BaseFilter.Apply(Bitmap image)
   at Program.main(String[] argv) in /dev/sample/Program.fs:line 11
```

Comment: are you running the program in the same computer where you compiled it?

Comment: @knocte Yes I do. Forgot to mention, OS is Linux Mint 18.1 64-bit.

Comment: and what version of .NET Core? how did you install it? did you have a previous installation before?

Comment: This method [is implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Drawing.Common/src/System/Drawing/Imaging/ColorPalette.cs#L36) in latest corefx (at least), so you should try install latest netcore

Comment: @knocte @Szer I previously had version `2.1.3` and now updated to `2.1.403`. Still not working though. If I don't include the `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` it complains about `Bitmap` type not found.

Comment: try to run this in a vanilla OS, where you install 2.1.403 from the start and there are no reinstallations, and report back; MissingMethodException are usually a symptom of bad installations

Comment: (also try specifying no version when adding the Drawing pkg?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Corecompat.System.Drawing.v2 version=5.2.0-preview1-r131` assembly rather than `CoreCompat.System.Drawing version version=1.0.0-beta006`.

In the relevant .fsproj file include:

```
<PackageReference Include="CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2" Version="5.2.0-preview1-r131" />
```

and remove any reference to any other CoreCompat.System.Drawing assembly that would conflict with this, and, restore the nugets in your solution.